# Add value to existing form field with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, append

i am trying to add the output of the following code (on page load)

```
<?php the_field('object_id'); ?>
```

to an field of an form with the id="sf_objekt". The field has an optional set value "ID". The output of the code should replace the "ID".

I tried using "append", but with no luck.

Any ideas? Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly undestood your question, the following snippet should do the trick:

```js
document.querySelector('#sf_objekt').value = "<?php the_field('object_id'); ?>"
```

```html
<input id="sf_objekt" type="text" />
```

Clearly the *<?php>* tag will be replaced with the output of the PHP function `the_field()` only if the page is ran through a PHP server.

Comment: Ty, I added the document.querySelector before the form. That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This code will auto fill in a form with the result of the php script.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="sf_objekt">
    </form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("sf_objekt").defaultValue= "<?php echo the_field('object_id'); ?>";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```